# How to plot a set of points on the ground in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to plot a set of points on the ground on my Unity3D project. The 2D plot of the points looks similar to this: 
[image: Plot][1].

The brute-force method would be to assign gameObjects to each points but since there are thousands of points it will be costly. I am looking for some possible usage of Unity Particle System to achieve my goal. In fact any possible methods would be fine.

My final goal is to highlight those points on the ground to indicate the path for my Player to follow.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: [This asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/camera-path-creator-84074) is awesome, you can modify it easily and instead of making camera follow the path, you can make player follow the path.       You can change those prefab and make something that you really want to see.       It is efficient too

Comment: You can ignore `Instantiate`-ing at once and use [Object pooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA) , this is very effective tutorial

Comment: The `LineRenderer` as suggested below is a really good option. I would also suggest filtering your points, if possible; for example, if two segments are near straight or cover only an infinitesimal distance, remove the mid-point.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Unity's [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html) component. It accepts an array of Vector3's which it uses to plot a line. You can assign the points from the inspector, or use code to assign the entire array at once, or point by point.

```
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;

public void AddPosition(Vector3 position)
{
    lineRenderer.positionCount += 1;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, position);
}

public void SetPositions(Vector3[] positionArray)
{
    lineRenderer.SetPositions(positionArray);
}
```

With the linerenderer, you can set all sorts of properties like color and width. You can also easilly disable and enable the entire object.

Comment: I have been considering using [Debug.Drawline](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) but I guess LineRenderer would be a better choice since it is visible in edit mode. I will do a little more research on other options and see what would be most suitable for my case. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider filtering your points. Humans don't need and often can't use the precision that machines can generate.  An example filter:

```
const float MinDistanceSqr = 0.00001f; // Min Distance of 0.001 (1mm)
const float MaxCosine = 0.999f; // Approx 2.57 degrees

private Vector3[] FilterPoints(Vector3[] source) {

    var filtered = new Stack<Vector3>(source.Length);

    // Push first point
    filtered.Push(source[0]);

    for ( var i = 1; i < source.Length; i++ ) {
        var step = filtered.Peek() - source[i];

        // Check Minimum Distance
        if (step.sqrMagnitude < MinDistanceSqr)
            continue; // ignore this point

        // if not last point
        if ( i + 1 < source.Length) {
            // Check Minimum Angle to next segment
            var nextStep = source[i] - source[i + 1];

            if (Vector3.Dot(step, nextStep) > MaxCosine)
                continue; // ignore this point
        }

        // Passed all filters, add to stack
        filtered.Push(source[i]);
    }


    return filtered.ToArray();
}
```